# what is a backing instance in react ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Although the term backing instance is referred in react docs a lot, I couldn't get what it means. From react docs :

> To interact with the browser, you'll need a reference to a DOM node.
>   You can attach a ref to any element, which allows you to reference the
>   **backing instance** of the component. This is useful if you need to
>   invoke imperative functions on the component, or want to access the
>   underlying DOM nodes.
>   [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html#refs-and-finddomnode)
>
> This simplified component API is intended for components that are pure
>   functions of their props. These components must not retain internal
>   state, do not have **backing instances**, and do not have the component
>   lifecycle methods.
>   [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions)
>
> Because stateless functions don't have a **backing instance**, you can't
>   attach a ref to a stateless function component. Normally this isn't an
>   issue, since stateless functions do not provide an imperative API.
>   Without an imperative API, there isn't much you could do with an
>   instance anyway. However, if a user wants to find the DOM node of a
>   stateless function component, they must wrap the component in a
>   stateful component (eg. ES6 class component) and attach the ref to the
>   stateful wrapper component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A backing instance is the object in memory which represents the node. This is where things like the state are usually stored.

So if you have a stateless component you won't have a backing instance because it is well stateless.

A few points regarding stateless components:

- No lifecycle methods
- No reference